# Prevent Open/Save dialog from solliciting external hard drives

Tags: macos, performance, dialog

I have several external drives, which I don't use constantly, and so they spin down, and rest.

Unfortunately for me, every time I have the "Open..." or "Save..." dialogs, Mac OS X spins these hard drives back up, even if the currently displayed folder does not belong to those drives, and even though nothing of those drives appears anywhere (no treeview on the side, no folder from those drives in the sidebar). I don't have Spotlight enabled.

Obviously a solution would be to disconnect/reconnect those drives, but that is something I would like to avoid.

Is there a way to tell Mac OS X not to eagerly/preemptively fire up the drives?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what did it for me, fingers crossed:

In an open/save file dialog, drag your external drives from the sidebar to nirvana. Next time you open/save a file, the disks should not spin up.

Kudos to [the original hint](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/os-always-waiting-for-ext-drive-to-spin-up.853024/?post=9419649#post-9419649).

Comment: Could you summarize the article you linked to? This will help out those in the future if the link ever dies out.

Comment: This is already the summary: "In an open/save file dialog, drag your external drives from the sidebar to nirvana. Next time you open/save a file, the disks should not spin up."

Comment: ..……to nirvana?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question because I was experiencing this same problem recently. Ultimately, I found the the order I had set in the Finder sidebar affected the behaviour. I had moved the external volumes and drives to the top of the sidebar and that made the Save-As dialogue box hang until the external drives spun up. I moved "Locations" back down below the typical "Favourites" and I get to interact with the Save-As window right away.